# Orange Pi 4g iot configuration and flash tool not working

Tags: sd-card, android-8.1-oreo, orange-pi

I am facing problem to flash `android 6.1` or `android 8.0` img file.

I follow orange pi user manual instruction but at last I download SMART PHONE FLASH TOOL and trying to flash `.img` file but when I click download button it stuck and nothing happen.

I also installed driver for win7 64 bit.

and also connect Laptop and Orange pi using USB Data Cable.

Please help me.

```
Orange Pi version     -    4G IoT

SD Card               -    Class 10, A1, 16GB

tool                  -    Smart Phone Flash tool as in user manual instruction
```

Answer (score 0):

SD card is not necessary, you can flash it to board internal storage.

To get it working you need to press and hold power button for 1-2 seconds, after board was connected to PC